# pdfbox get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmap

Tags: java, pdfbox

i am using pdfbox to render a pdf file to image, but i got ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when run TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmap method, cmapTable is empty and cmapTable.getCmaps()[0] led to out of bounds, here is the call stack

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TrueTypeFont.getUnicodeCmap(TrueTypeFont.java:566)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:183)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.<init>(PDCIDFontType2.java:70)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createDescendantFont(PDFontFactory.java:125)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.<init>(PDType0Font.java:128)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFontFactory.createFont(PDFontFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDResources.getFont(PDResources.java:123)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.operator.text.SetFontAndSize.process(SetFontAndSize.java:60)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processOperator(PDFStreamEngine.java:815)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStreamOperators(PDFStreamEngine.java:472)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processStream(PDFStreamEngine.java:446)
at org.apache.pdfbox.contentstream.PDFStreamEngine.processPage(PDFStreamEngine.java:149)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PageDrawer.drawPage(PageDrawer.java:189)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderPage(PDFRenderer.java:208)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImage(PDFRenderer.java:139)
at org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(PDFRenderer.java:80)
```

and here is the getUnicodeCmap method in pdfbox

```
public CmapSubtable getUnicodeCmap(boolean isStrict) throws IOException
{
    CmapTable cmapTable = getCmap();
    if (cmapTable == null)
    {
        if (isStrict)
        {
            throw new IOException("The TrueType font does not contain a 'cmap' table");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    CmapSubtable cmap = cmapTable.getSubtable(CmapTable.PLATFORM_UNICODE,
                                              CmapTable.ENCODING_UNICODE_2_0_FULL);
    if (cmap == null)
    {
        cmap = cmapTable.getSubtable(CmapTable.PLATFORM_UNICODE,
                                     CmapTable.ENCODING_UNICODE_2_0_BMP);
    }
    if (cmap == null)
    {
        cmap = cmapTable.getSubtable(CmapTable.PLATFORM_WINDOWS,
                                     CmapTable.ENCODING_WIN_UNICODE_BMP);
    }
    if (cmap == null)
    {
        // Microsoft's "Recommendations for OpenType Fonts" says that "Symbol" encoding
        // actually means "Unicode, non-standard character set"
        cmap = cmapTable.getSubtable(CmapTable.PLATFORM_WINDOWS,
                                     CmapTable.ENCODING_WIN_SYMBOL);
    }
    if (cmap == null)
    {
        if (isStrict)
        {
            throw new IOException("The TrueType font does not contain a Unicode cmap");
        }
        else
        {
            // fallback to the first cmap (may not be Unicode, so may produce poor results)
            cmap = cmapTable.getCmaps()[0];
        }
    }
    return cmap;
}
```

i found this file contains fonts with custom encoding, and there is a "warm" comment in the pdfbox's code: fallback to the first cmap (may not be Unicode, so may produce poor results). So I suspect that the custom font encoding caused this problem, is this correct?
[image: pdf fonts encoding]

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? This looks like a bug that has been fixed in 2016: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3426

Comment: You should probably share a pdf that demonstrates the issue.